# drupal form field not loading correct data

Tags: drupal-7

I am building my first Drupal 7 module and am having trouble with the screen to edit a fieldable entity. I am using field_attach_form and it is working great for all accept one field which is displaying the field default rather than the current content of that field for that entity.

I have a text field, a number field, a number of Boolean fields and the one list_text field which is failing.

Any ideas what I a doing incorrectly? Code below is what I think is needed but please do let me know if you need more.

Code to create the field in hook_enable:

```
if (!field_info_field('field_available')) {
    $field = array (
      'field_name' => 'field_available',
      'type' => 'list_text',
      'settings' => array(
      'allowed_values' => array('No', 'Provisionally', 'Yes'),
    ),
 );
 field_create_field($field);
```

Code to create the instance, also in hook_enable:

```
 if (!field_info_instance('appointments_status', 'field_available', 'appointments_status')) {
   $instance = array(
     'field_name' => 'field_available',
     'entity_type' => 'appointments_status',
     'bundle' => 'appointments_status',
     'label' => t('Available?'),
     'required' => TRUE,
     'default_value' => array(array('value' => 'No')),
     'description' => t('Set to No if appointments with this status make this slot unavailable, Provisionally means that it will only reserve a space temporarily'),
   );
 field_create_instance($instance);
```

This entity has only the one bundle with the same name as the entity.

The code to create the URL in hook_menu:

```
 $items['admin/appointments/appointments_statii/%/edit'] = array(
   'title' => 'Edit appointment status',
   'description' => 'Edit the parameters of the selected status code',
   'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
   'page arguments' => array('appointments_status_edit_form',3),
   'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
   'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
 );
```

The form function is:

```
 function appointments_status_edit_form($form, &$form_state) {
   // Get the status id from the form_state args
   $status_id = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0];

   // Load the chosen status entity
   $status = entity_load_single('appointments_status', $status_id);

   // Set up the fields for the form
   field_attach_form('appointments_status', $status, $form, $form_state);

   $form['submit'] = array(
     '#type' => 'submit',
     '#value' => 'Save changes',
     '#weight' => 99,
   );
   return $form;
 }
```

I have used the Devel module's dpm to check that the data is loaded correctly by entity_load_single and it is.

Thanks
 Rory

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my own question!
I was also programmatically loading some entities and was not loading this field with the numbers that a list_text field stores, instead I was loading the visual text.
I used a metadata wrapper and the code looked like this:

```
$w_appointments_status->$appointments_availability= 'Yes';
```

I changed it to:

```
$w_appointments_status->$appointments_availability = 2;
```

In this example 'Yes' was the third allowed value - hence 2.
So the code in my question was in fact correct although I have since added 'widget' and 'formatter' parameters to the instance.

I am sorry if this got some of you scratching your heads thinking ' but that code is correct'!!
Regards
Rory